# ImageMagick - Suppress warning messages

Tags: imagemagick, cmd

I have the following which I use to get the total pages in a PDF document:

```
identify -format %n test.pdf
```

I then strip all non numeric characters to get a single integer from the response.

Occasionally the following error is produced which causes the above to produce the incorrect number of pages as they're are other numbers not related to the pages in the response.

```
   **** Warning: Fonts with Subtype = /TrueType should be embedded.
             The following fonts were not embedded:
                    Arial
                    Arial,Bold
                    Arial,Italic
                    Times New Roman

    **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
    **** The file was produced by:
    **** >>>> Microsoft« Office Word 2007 <<<<
    **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
    **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
    **** specification.

    9
```

The "9" is the number of pages in the document.

How to do I supress the warning messages, I've attempted using the "-quiet" flag but the message is still produced.

Comment: Ive managed to get around this by exploding the response by line breaks and only using the last that contains the page count.

Comment: The warning might not be an Imagemagick one but could be from Ghostscript.

Answer (score 4):

From identify's man page:

> -quiet               suppress all warning messages

So, your command should look like the following in order to suppress warning messages:

```
identify -quiet -format %n test.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

The warning goes to stderr so a simple output redirect will do the trick:

```
 identify -format %n test.pdf 2>/dev/null
```